# Getting "ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53) additional info: no global superior knowledge" when trying to add new objectClass to openLDAP

Tags: openldap

I have created new schema which looks like this

```
attributetype ( 2.25.3236588
        NAME 'x-candidateNumber'
        DESC 'Candidate number'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32768} )


attributetype ( 2.25.3536282
        NAME 'x-candidateFullName'
        DESC 'Candidate name'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32768} )

attributetype ( 2.25.6587875
        NAME 'x-candidateTitleBeforeName'
        DESC 'Candidate title before name'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32768} )

attributetype ( 2.25.6164147
        NAME 'x-candidateTitleAfterName'
        DESC 'Candidate title after name'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32768} )

attributetype ( 2.25.1702122
        NAME 'x-candidateBirthNumber'
        DESC 'Candidate title after name'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32768} )

attributetype ( 2.25.3134432
        NAME 'x-candidateListedAt'
        DESC 'Candidate listed at'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32768} )

attributetype ( 2.25.3682754
        NAME 'x-candidateErasedAt'
        DESC 'Candidate erased at'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32768} )

attributetype ( 2.25.5497561
        NAME 'x-candidateNote'
        DESC 'Candidate note'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32768} )

attributetype ( 2.25.9736218
        NAME 'x-candidateStatus'
        DESC 'Candidate status'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32768} )

objectclass ( 2.25.1798306
        NAME 'ekcrCandidate'
        DESC 'RFC1274: simple security object'
        SUP ( top $ person $ organizationalPerson $ inetOrgPerson )
        STRUCTURAL
        MUST (cn $ ou)
        MAY ( x-candidateNumber $ x-candidateFullName $ x-candidateTitleBeforeName $
                x-candidateBirthNumber $ x-candidateTitleAfterName $ x-candidateListedAt $
                x-candidateErasedAt $ x-candidateNote $ x-candidateStatus
         ))
```

I added this schema into `schema_convert.conf` file:

```
include /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/collective.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/corba.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/duaconf.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/java.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/misc.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/openldap.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/pmi.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/ekcrconcipient.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/ekcrcandidate.schema
include /etc/ldap/schema/ekcrlegalofficer.schema
```

Then I converted the schema into an `ldif` file

```shell
slaptest -f schema_convert.conf -F /tmp/ldif_output
```

It generated a file which I modified as explained [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/how-to-add-a-new-schema-to-openldap-2-4-11-a-700452/#post3423916) in step 4.
Resulting `cn={14}ekcrlegalofficer.ldif` file now looks like this:

```
dn: cn=ekcrlegalofficer
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: ekcrlegalofficer
olcAttributeTypes: {0}( 2.25.7702021 NAME 'x-legalOfficerNumber' DESC 'Legal o
 fficer number' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{
 32768} )
olcAttributeTypes: {1}( 2.25.960171 NAME 'x-legalOfficerFullName' DESC 'Legal
 officer name' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{3
 2768} )
olcAttributeTypes: {2}( 2.25.196694 NAME 'x-legalOfficerTitleBeforeName' DESC
 'Legal officer title before name' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1
 .1466.115.121.1.15{32768} )
olcAttributeTypes: {3}( 2.25.7643140 NAME 'x-legalOfficerTitleAfterName' DESC
 'Legal officer title after name' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.
 1466.115.121.1.15{32768} )
olcAttributeTypes: {4}( 2.25.1064416 NAME 'x-legalOfficerListedAt' DESC 'Legal
  officer listed at' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.
 1.15{32768} )
olcAttributeTypes: {5}( 2.25.1005975 NAME 'x-legalOfficerErasedAt' DESC 'Legal
  Officer erased at' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.
 1.15{32768} )
olcAttributeTypes: {6}( 2.25.5513419 NAME 'x-legalOfficerNote' DESC 'Legal Off
 icer note' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{3276
 8} )
olcAttributeTypes: {7}( 2.25.4535859 NAME 'x-legalOfficerStatus' DESC 'Legal O
 fficer status' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{
 32768} )
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 2.25.6182638 NAME 'ekcrLegalOfficer' DESC 'RFC1274: sim
 ple security object' SUP ( top $ person $ organizationalPerson $ inetOrgPerso
 n ) STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ ou ) MAY ( x-legalOfficerNumber $ x-legalOfficerFu
 llName $ x-legalOfficerTitleBeforeName $ x-legalOfficerTitleAfterName $ x-leg
 alOfficerListedAt $ x-legalOfficerErasedAt $ x-legalOfficerNote $ x-legalOffi
 cerStatus ) )
```

Then I tried to add this new `objectClass` with

```shell
ldapadd -D "cn=admin,cn=config" -W -f cn={14}ekcrlegalofficer.ldif
```

which resulted in this

```
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
        additional info: no global superior knowledge
```

I understood, this error might occur when you are trying to add new record into wrong database but since I'm trying to create new object class this shouldn't be my case.

It actually worked for me in the past, but then I reconfigured my openLDAP server using

```shell
dpkg-reconfigre slapd
```

and since then I'm facing this issue.

I'm stucked on this on third day now and I'm really desperate, I would be really gratefull for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you're trying to create an object with this distinguishedName:

```
dn: cn=ekcrlegalofficer
```

That's invalid; the schema needs to exist "inside" an existing hierarchy. The "no global superior knowledge" error means "I have no idea where to place this object".

Take a look at the existing schemas, which will look something like:

```
dn: cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config
```

You probably want your `dn` to look like:

```
dn: cn=ekcrlegalofficer,cn=schema,cn=config
```

Comment: Yes, it was the problem, thank you!